# How to change prefix in node name in PHP using SimpleXML?

Tags: xml, node.js

I'm editing an XML file and the root node has the prefix "cfdi" for all children nodes. When I append a new node it includes the prefix cfdi but I'd like to change it for another prefix. How can I do that?

Sample:

```
<cfdi:comprobante>
<cfdi:emisor></cfdi:emisor>
<cfdi:receptor></cfdi:receptor>
<cfdi:addenda>
     <cfdi:factura />
     <cfdi:ordenCompra />
</cfdi:addenda>
</cfdi:comprobante>
```

My code is this

```
$Addenda = $xml->addChild('Addenda');
$factura = $Addenda->addChild('htx:factura');
$oc = $Addenda->addChild('htx:ordenCompra');
```

My expected output must be like this.

```
<cfdi:comprobante>
<cfdi:emisor></cfdi:emisor>
<cfdi:receptor></cfdi:receptor>
<cfdi:addenda>
    <htx:factura />  
    <htx:ordenCompra />
</cfdi:addenda><br>
</cfdi:comprobante>
```

Comment: For XML, the answer would be to use the namespace-aware version of `addChild` or equilvalent. But this isn't well-formed XML (since the `br` tags aren't terminated), so I'm not going to guess.

Comment: Thanks Keshlam, I had a mistake when posted my original message. What I need is to add the "htx:factura" and "htx:odenCompra". How can I do it?

Comment: In that case, I think my answer applies: Use namespace-aware operations, rather than the archaic and would-be-deprecated-if-W3C-had-a-deprecation-mechanism non-namespace-aware versions.

Comment: uuuuh, :) even I have created several pages in PHP I'm novice in PHP and XML, could you please give to me more details??

Comment: Any one, please help me

Comment: Finaly I did it by myself using some portions from several webpage. I have had to use DOM instead SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code instead of `$Addenda->addChild('htx:factura')`

```
$Addenda->addChild('htx:htx:factura');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are working with Mexican CFDI, and I assume that your XML document is much larger.

It **must** include xml namespace declarations, like `xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"`. The namespace is `http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3` and the prefix is `cfdi`, so, any node that is prefixed with `cfdi:` belongs to `http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3` namespace.

In order to add a new namespace you must specify the namespace in the third parameter `$Addenda->addChild('htx:factura', '', NAMESPACE_HERE);`, follow the example:

```php
$comprobante = new SimpleXmlElement('<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" version="3.3"/>');
$factura = $comprobante->addChild('htx:factura', '', 'http://example.com/htx-namespace');
echo $comprobante->asXml();
```

will produce:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" version="3.3">
  <htx:factura xmlns:htx="http://example.com/htx-namespace"/>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

PD: you might find some help about PHP and CFDI on phpCfdi community.